# How to read key value from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have got below xml format file called `"ResourceData.xml"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <key name="customPageTitle">
    <value>Publish Resources to Custom Page</value>
  </key>
</root>
```

Now I want to write a function which take the key `"name"` as input and will return its value element data, in above case it will return `"Publish Resources to Custom Page"` if we pass the key name `"customPageTitle"`, I think will open the XML file and then it will read.

Please suggest!!

Comment: Please do some basic research yourself before posting a question, e.g. google(read xml c#) ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```
public string GetXMLValue(string XML, string searchTerm)
{
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(XML);
  XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("root/key");
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    XmlAttributeCollection nodeAtt = node.Attributes;
    if(nodeAtt["name"].Value.ToString() == searchTerm)
    {
      XmlDocument childNode = new XmlDocument();
      childNode.LoadXml(node.OuterXml);
      return childNode.SelectSingleNode("key/value").InnerText;
    }
    else
    {
      return "did not match any documents";
    }
  }
  return "No key value pair found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into an XDocument. Replace [input] with method input variable.

```
var value = doc.Descendants("key")
                 .Where(k => k.Attribute("name").Value.Equals([input]))
                 .Select(e => e.Elements("value").Value)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is untested code so there might be errors in this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String GetViaName(String search, String xml)
{
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

  return (from c in doc.Descendants("key")
    where ((String)c.Attribute("name")).Equals(search)
    select (String)c.Element("value")).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return doc.Descendants("key")
           .Where(c => ((String)c.Attribute("name")).Equals(search))
           .Select(c => (String)c.Element("value"))
           .FirstOrDefault()
           .Trim();
```