# How to read complex XML in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML, I need to get the price by searching for the Model Value and StoreName value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Results>
 <Product>
  <Model>X-180</Model>
  <Prices>
   <Price value="180.0" StoreName="StoreA" />
   <Price value="181.0" StoreName="StoreB" />
   <Price value="181.0" StoreName="StoreC" />
  </Prices>
 </Product>
 <Product>
  <Model>LB621120S</Model>
  <Prices>
   <Price value="2100.0" StoreName="StoreD" />
   <Price value="2120" StoreName="StoreF" />
   <Price value="4050" StoreName="StoreG" />
  </Prices>
 </Product>
</Results>
```

For example:
If i run a function to get the price of Model="LB621120S" and StoreName="StoreF"
I should get the price: 2120

Is this possible in XmlTextReader?

Comment: very possible, have you tried anything yet that is giving you problems?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read key value from XML in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893884/how-to-read-key-value-from-xml-in-c-sharp)

Comment: welcome to SO!  but a question like this is easily solved with a little googling

Comment: This is bad XML.  Do you have any control over changing the structure, or are you stuck with it?  The way it is currently structured, Prices does not belong to Model.  The only way to guess they are related is because they both belong to the same Product.  My guess is that Model should semantically be an attribute of Product, not a child entity of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var reader = new XmlTextReader(<XmlPathFileName>);
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(reader);
reader.Close();

var root = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (root == null)
            return;

var node = root.SelectSingleNode("/Results/Product[Model='LB621120S']/Prices/Price[@StoreName='StoreF']");
```

Answer (score 4):

This XPath will return the `Price` element you want:

```
/Results/Product[Model='LB621120S']/Prices/Price[@StoreName='StoreF']
```

Comment: and [How to query XML with an XPath expression by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)

Answer (score 1):

using LINQ:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 var value =
    doc.Descendants("Product")
    .First(p => p.Descendants("Model").First().Value == "LB621120S")
     .Descendants("Price")
      .First(p => p.Attribute("StoreName").Value == "StoreF")
       .Attribute("value").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xdoc.Descendants("Product")
    .Where(p => (string)p.Element("Model") == model)
    .Elements("Price")
    .Where(p => (string)p.Attribute("StoreName") == store)
    .Select(p => (decimal)p.Attribute("value"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```